# Does $\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+\ln(x)} \, dx$ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I'm not sure if this should be solved using comparison test or absolute integration. How can I tell if $\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+\ln(x)} \, dx$ diverges or converges?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello there, please read "https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question", and also read: "https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference"

Comment: Hint: $x+\log x<2x$

Comment: @SineoftheTime So solving $\int_{e}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2x} \, dx \quad$, the original integral diverges?

Comment: yes, if $x+\log x<2x$, you have $\frac{1}{x+\log x}> \frac1{2x}$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since $x> \ln (x)>0  \ \forall x>1 $  so that $\frac{1}{x+ \ln(x)}<\frac{1}{2x}$

then $\int_e ^ \infty \frac{dx}{2x}<\int_e ^ \infty \frac{dx}{x+\ln(x)}$ and $\int_e ^ \infty \frac{dx}{2x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\lim\limits_{b \to \infty }\ln(b) -1 \right)\to \infty $ so it diverge then $\int_e ^ \infty \frac{dx}{x+\ln(x)}$ also diverge